# How to scale two ranges knowing the 0 point value?

Tags: math

I need to scale something like `[MINs, 0, MAXs] to [MINa, STARTa, MAXa]`

So, given `MINs, MAXs, MINa, STARTa, MAXa`: I need f that solves:

> f(MINs) = MINa
>
> f(0)    = STARTa
>
> f(MAXs) = MAXa

Any ideas on how to get f?

As an example:
MINa = -80, STARTa = 10, MAXa = 110, MINs = -32768, MAXs = 32767

Comment: For fitting any 3 points, a quadratic is what you want.

Comment: @ThomasJager Thanks for the hint. It will do